# Write sql query to wrap row data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one requirement to show data in using SQL query only.
Table name: EMP_DEPT

```
    DEPARTMENT  |   EMPLOYEE    |   SALARY
    DEPT1       |   ABC         |   20000
    DEPT1       |   MNO         |   30000
    DEPT1       |   XYZ         |   25000
    DEPT2       |   DEF         |   42000
    DEPT2       |   GHI         |   35000
    DEPT3       |   JKL         |   36000
```

and what I am expecting result in following way

```
    DEPARTMENT  |   EMPLOYEE    |   SALARY
    DEPT1       |   ABC         |   20000
                |   MNO         |   30000
                |   XYZ         |   25000
    DEPT2       |   DEF         |   42000
                |   GHI         |   35000
    DEPT3       |   JKL         |   36000
```

What will be the select query to print like this. Using MSSQL as DB

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the first time a department appears, and use a `CASE` statement to show the department name or blank.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY EMPLOYEE) = 1
        THEN DEPARTMENT
        ELSE ''
    END AS DEPARTMENT,
    EMPLOYEE,
    SALARY
FROM EMP_DEPT
ORDER BY EMP_DEPT.DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: Hi Ross, I have try this query it works with single issue. The problem is In above example DEPT1 shows at XYZ employees row which I want it at ABC employee row. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can use `''` or `NULL` as you wish. Maybe you want to order in partition by `EMPLOYEE`.

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN DEPARTMENT ELSE '' END  as DEPARTMENT,
   EMPLOYEE,
   SALARY
FROM
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
   FROM EMP_DEPT
) A
```