# Wrap query result in row

Tags: sql-server

Extending question which is there on [Write sql query to wrap row data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217867/write-sql-query-to-wrap-row-data)

```
    DEPARTMENT  |   SUB_DEPT    |   EMPLOYEE    |   SALARY
    DEPT1       |   SUB_DEPT1   |   ABC         |   20000
    DEPT1       |   SUB_DEPT1   |   DEF         |   30000
    DEPT1       |   SUB_DEPT2   |   GHI         |   25000
    DEPT1       |   SUB_DEPT2   |   JKL         |   42000
    DEPT2       |   SUB_DEPT3   |   MNO         |   42500
    DEPT2       |   SUB_DEPT3   |   PQR         |   35000
    DEPT3       |   SUB_DEPT4   |   STU         |   36000
    DEPT3       |   SUB_DEPT5   |   VWX         |   36040
```

retrieve like

```
    DEPARTMENT  |   SUB_DEPT    |   EMPLOYEE    |   SALARY
    DEPT1       |   SUB_DEPT1   |   ABC         |   20000
                |               |   DEF         |   30000
                |   SUB_DEPT2   |   GHI         |   25000
                |               |   JKL         |   42000
    DEPT2       |   SUB_DEPT3   |   MNO         |   42500
                |               |   PQR         |   35000
    DEPT3       |   SUB_DEPT4   |   STU         |   36000
                |   SUB_DEPT5   |   VWX         |   36040
```

It means 
1) Wrapping must apply for two columns.
2) Wrapping text must be for first row i.e. DEPT1 must present at first row only, DEPT2 present for 5th row.

Please help me out for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the same process as your original post.  Create a `row_number()` for each unique department, then do the same thing for each unique department *and* sub_dept partition:

```
select 
  case when deptrn = 1 then department else '' end department,
  case when SubDeptRn = 1 then sub_dept else '' end sub_dept,
  employee,
  salary
from
(
  select department, sub_dept, employee, salary,
    row_number() over(partition by department order by department, employee) DeptRn,
    row_number() over(partition by department, sub_dept order by department, sub_dept, employee) SubDeptRn
  from yourtable
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d45c/5)

Result:

```
| DEPARTMENT |  SUB_DEPT | EMPLOYEE | SALARY |
----------------------------------------------
|      DEPT1 | SUB_DEPT1 |      ABC |  20000 |
|            |           |      DEF |  30000 |
|            | SUB_DEPT2 |      GHI |  25000 |
|            |           |      JKL |  42000 |
|      DEPT2 | SUB_DEPT3 |      MNO |  42500 |
|            |           |      PQR |  35000 |
|      DEPT3 | SUB_DEPT4 |      STU |  36000 |
|            | SUB_DEPT5 |      VWX |  36040 |
```